# Add shadow to the frame/panel/label/... in wx Python

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I mainly use C++ and Qt but now I'm forced to code some python stuff. I'm wondering if it is possible to add fancy shadow to python's wx gui elements? Something similar that can be done with Qt/C++:

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *g1 = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(this);
ui->pushButton->setGraphicsEffect(g1);
```